# Can someone provide a good explanation of Dagger 2?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm really having a hard time understanding the Dagger 2 Dependency injection system.

I understand the use of the `@Inject` annotation to tell Dagger we need to provide an instance of some type to here.

But, I don't understand the various roles of the other components such as: `@Module` , `@Component` , `@Provides` and how they work together to provide the appropriate instance to the appropriate dependency.

Can someone please explain it simply and concisely ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> **@Module**: Modules are classes whose methods provide dependencies, so we
> define a class and annotate it with **@Module**, thus, Dagger will know
> where to find the dependencies in order to satisfy them when
> constructing class instances. One important feature of modules is that
> they have been designed to be partitioned and composed together (for
> instance we will see that in our apps we can have multiple composed
> modules).
>
> **@Component**: Components basically are injectors, let’s say a bridge between
> **@Inject** and **@Module**, which its main responsibility is to put
> both together. They just give you instances of all the types you
> defined, for example, we must annotate an interface with **@Component**
> and list all the **@Modules** that will compose that component, and if any
> of them is missing, we get errors at compile time. All the components
> are aware of the scope of dependencies it provides through its
> modules.
>
> **@Provide**: Inside modules we define methods containing this annotation
> which tells Dagger how we want to construct and provide those
> mentioned dependencies.

I advise you to read this:

- [Tasting Dagger 2 on Android by Fernando Cejas](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/04/11/tasting-dagger-2-on-android/)
- [Dependency Injection with Dagger 2 (Devoxx 2014) by Jake Wharton](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-devoxx-2014)
- [Dependency Injection with Dagger 2](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2)
- [Dependency injection with Dagger 2 - the API by froger_mcs](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-the-api/)
- [Dependency injection with Dagger 2 - Custom scopes by froger_mcs](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/)

I guess it will help to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can find useful Dagger2 sample projects and tutorials here.

[Dagger 2 working sample project with MVP](https://github.com/rkandoroidrepo/android-dagger2-example)

[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ_qek0hGkM&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuA2ioi4soDZKz8euUQnJW65)

[Practical tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qZh6Fyrz-k&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8AOAspC3DHoBNZIBHbIOsC&index=2&t=0s%20(edited))

Answer (score 0):

Annotation Used in Dagger 2 and their purpose

1. @Inject - This is used over the fields, constructor, or method and indicates that dependencies are requested. Here Dagger will construct an instance of the annotated class.
2. @Module - In simple layman terms, over the class which is used to construct objects and provide the dependencies. Whenever a class is annotated with @Module,  Dagger simply knows where to find the dependencies.
3. @Provide - As the name suggests this guy's job is to provide the instance. This is used over the method in the module class that will return the object.
4. @Component - Bridge between your Inject & Module. The module class doesn’t provide dependency directly to requesting class, it uses a component interface.

I would definitely recommend going through the links provided by ArtKorchagin.